# R / Salesforce Datetime integration

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I'm having an issue with a particular format of `ISO 8601` datetimes in R - Examples:

```
2016-12-28T13:00:56.000Z
2016-12-28T13:03:10.000Z
2016-12-28T13:08:26.000Z
2016-12-28T13:13:00.000Z
2016-12-28T13:34:49.000Z
2016-12-28T13:42:44.000Z
2016-12-28T13:51:43.000Z
2016-12-28T13:52:30.000Z
2016-12-28T13:53:03.000Z
```

So far, I haven't been successful using `lubridate` to parse and I'm considering using `regex` to break this up first and remove the T/Z. Or is there something I can do with `strptime`? That could also be an option. Ideally, this would be piped for all instances in the list/vector for instance:

```
df %>% 
select(datetime) %>% 
sapply(as.character) %>% 
parse_date_time('YmdHMS') -> df$datetime
```

The actual issue here is that my object type was originally a list - after an `unlist` several different parsing methods worked immediately. Always keep tabs on your object types!

Comment: I didn't get an error parsing `d <- "2016-12-28T13:00:56.000Z"` with `parse_date_time(d, 'YmdHMS')`  #
[1] "2016-12-28 13:00:56 UTC". I had been expecting that the "T" in the middle was the snag but did not seem to be the issue. Did you perhaps fail to load either dplyr or magrittr package? (Also no error with: `d %>% 
    sapply(as.character) %>% 
    parse_date_time('YmdHMS') `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stick it into [`anytime()`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime), it gets *many* formats right (without the need to specify them) and certainly works with ISO 8601:

```
R> tvec <- read.csv(text="2016-12-28T13:00:56.000Z
2016-12-28T13:03:10.000Z
2016-12-28T13:08:26.000Z
2016-12-28T13:13:00.000Z
2016-12-28T13:34:49.000Z
2016-12-28T13:42:44.000Z
2016-12-28T13:51:43.000Z
2016-12-28T13:52:30.000Z
2016-12-28T13:53:03.000Z", header=FALSE)[,1]
R>
```

That just assigned your data (shown in a not-too-reproducible format).  Then:

```
R> library(anytime)     ## load package, and we're basically done
R> anytime(tvec)
[1] "2016-12-28 13:00:56 CST" "2016-12-28 13:03:10 CST" "2016-12-28 13:08:26 CST" 
[4] "2016-12-28 13:13:00 CST" "2016-12-28 13:34:49 CST" "2016-12-28 13:42:44 CST" 
[7] "2016-12-28 13:51:43 CST" "2016-12-28 13:52:30 CST" "2016-12-28 13:53:03 CST"
R>
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked this. Fantastic library and will definitely become my go-to for datetime input.

Comment: Glad it helps. It's pretty new (less than six months) but yet I now use it daily too ... and had wanted something like it for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

For the base R solution:

```
> as.POSIXct("2016-12-28T13:00:56.000Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
[1] "2016-12-28 13:00:56 CET"
```